# Blender 2.9 - Grease pencil stroke too faint - how to reedit existing strokes?

Tags: grease-pencil

As I use a black color, full opacity, I am a bit surprised my strokes look like pale crayon

I tried raising the opacity or the thickness but it does not help

How can I make it full dark ?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

sculpt mode (seriously?) helps in such a case

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=W1pt6xYES9I